# return values and calling other methods in Java

Tags: java

I can't find my mistake in the last part of the code. The last part (`printMyProgress()`) method doesn't work correctly.

Method called `printMyProgress()` that calls `printStudentProgress()`, passing as arguments the values returned from calling `getMyName()` and `getMyTimeSoFar()` methods.

```
public class first {
String getMyName() {
  String name = "Nat";
    return name;  
}
int getMyTimeSoFar() {
    int time=0;
    return time;
}

 void printStudentProgress(String name, int time) {
     String minute ="";
     if (time>1) 
     minute = "minutes";
     else minute= "minute";
     print (name + " took " +time+ " "+  minute+" to reach Q7 in the Exam");     
 }

   int printMyProgress() {
       String name = "Nat";
       int time=0;
       printStudentProgress(name, time);
       return printMyProgress();  
   }
}
```

Comment: Why did you make `printMyProgress()` recursive?  I don't see any reason for it to call itself.

Comment: Could you give us a little more information when you say it "doesn't work correctly" ?  Even moreso, perhaps what your desired result is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this statement inside method `printMyProgress`:

```
return printMyProgress();
```

the method will recurse forever. If you do not depend upon the method returning a value, make the method return nothing (using `void` keyword instead of `int`) and remove the return statement:

```
void printMyProgress() {
   String name = "Nat";
   int time=0;
   printStudentProgress(name, time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last method is recursing (calling itself). As there is no code to break out of this recursion, the application will eventually (quickly) run out of memory and crash.